# Is there a way to dynamically execute except blocks?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that'll make walls of `except` blocks more human-readable, but when a program tries to dynamically execute them with `exec()`, Python returns a syntax error.

```py
def error_handling(errors_messages):
    output = ''
    for error in errors_messages:
        output = (output + 'except ' + error + ':\n'
                           '    print(\"' + errors_messages[error] + '")\n')
    return output


try:
    # stuff goes here
    pass
exec(error_handling({
    'NameError':  "Name error message",
    'IndexError': "Index error message"
    }))
```

Adding a dummy error in front of the `exec()` function doesn't seem to help much, as it then seems to forget about the `try` block.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is hardly more readable than `except NameError: print('Name error message')`…?!

Comment: What you're trying is not possible. `except` is part of the syntax of `try`, it has to be literally in the code. Functions are not macros, the result is not substituted into the code text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is! Accessing the type of the exception:

```py
data = {
    NameError: 'Name error message',
    IndexError: 'Index error message',
}

try:
    foo
except Exception as e:
    error_message = data.get(type(e))
    if error_message is not None:
        print(error_message)
```

Comment: kinda ancillary, but in the case of `if error_message is not None:`  is false, the error should probably be raised, instead of silently ignored.

Comment: and also, this is going to not really maintain the semantics of `except`, you'd want to loop over data and check `if issubclass(type(e), klass)`

Comment: so, you probably should do something like `except (*data,) as e:` but you still have to account for subclasses

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Stop being pedantic. The answer is to reproduce exactly what the OP wants.